# What is the meaning of url("#foobar");

Tags: css

I'm working on a css concatenator, and as part of that I have to do URL to absolute URL rewriting.

As part of that, I don't rewrite any absolute URLs (starts with http, https, etc).  In the Django project, they use these as the URL formats to ignore:

```
body {
    background: url("#foobar");
    background: url("http:foobar");
    background: url("https:foobar");
    background: url("data:foobar");
    background: url("//foobar");
}
```

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/staticfiles_tests/project/documents/cached/css/ignored.css

I've seen all of those except the `background: url("#foobar");` format.

I also see it in their test cases to define behavior:

```
div {
    behavior: url("#default#VML");
}
```

https://github.com/django/django/blob/86f4459f9e3c035ec96578617605e93234bf2700/tests/staticfiles_tests/project/documents/cached/css/fragments.css

What does "url('#foobar')" reference?  Is it valid css, or a MSIE hack or something?

Comment: I'd assume it would be a [URL fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) or hash.

Comment: I'd found that wikipedia article prior to asking, unfortunately it doesn't discuss a URL Fragment meaning in this case.  I've also skimmed and searched http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986 and didn't find anything that helped -- though those are dense and long and I may have missed the section that discusses them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is used to refer to an [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) image in the document.

For example, from [Using SVG](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/):

```
<svg ...>
  <filter id="pictureFilter" >
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
  </filter> 
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.ground:hover {
  filter: url(#pictureFilter);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I'd never seen that technique used before.

Comment: @Ted - I've seen it used a lot *in* SVG, but I can't actually find an example using it in SVG. I'm still trying to make sure I'm correct...

Comment: @Ted - OK - I can't get it to work with `background`, so I think I'll delete my answer soon.

Comment: It looks like their test-case is for convenience, not actually a valid use.  I'll modify the title of the question as you actually answered it for me.